# VSCode Focus Active Editor Group when explorer is Focused Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode 1.64.1 on Windows, I'm trying to create some conditional shortcuts for focusing.

When the file explorer is **not** focused I would like `ctrl+0` to focus the active editor group. When the active editor group **is** focused, I would like `ctrl+0` to focus the explorer. I tried the following, but it only partially works.

Currently, hitting `ctrl+0` will focus the explorer, but hitting `ctrl+0` again when the explorer is focused does not focus the active editor group as desired:

```json
//keybindings.json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+0",
    "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
    "when": "!editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+0",
    "command": "workbench.action.focusSideBar",
    "when": "!explorerFocus"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a `explorerFocus` context key.  The below does work:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+0",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
  "when": "!editorTextFocus"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+0",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusSideBar",
  "when": "!filesExplorerFocus"                  // change here
}
```

Apparently when you use a non-existent context key that `when` clause is not evaluated at all - as if it wasn't there.  And since evaluation of the keybindings is from the bottom of the file up - first one from bottom wins - your `focusActiveEditorGroup` command will never be seen.